# Create my "Ok Google"

Tags: android, dialogflow-es

I need to create my own "Ok Google", when My user open my app, the app should start the mic to listen every words that my user say, when my user say a "previous configured word" the app should start to record the audio and to send to my api.ai(this i alredy does) but after I got the api.ai return I need to convert that text to speach(this i already does too) and wait to my user aswer(for 10 seconds or more depends on config) and if my user say something get that and send to api.ai again. and will loop this until my user close my app.

It`s possible to do this?

Comment: You need to provide some code and a better explanation, it's not clear what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

All of what you say is possible except retrieving raw audio.  The Actions on Google platform will take the audio and transcribe it to text for you so you don't need access to the raw audio.

I'd recommend checking out [the Actions on Google getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/actions/get-started/) to learn how to do what you describe.

Comment: only works in English :D I need portugues to start :D

Comment: You might want to update your question to specify that.